# Google Fit REST api support for new HealthDataTypes

Tags: android, google-fit

I have written an android app using google fit rest api's to query and display various fitness parameters.
But i have not been able to do the same with the health datatypes : blood glucose and blood pressure. As far as i can see, everyone seems to have just copy/pasted the googleapi documentation on writing bp/sugar data. No one seemed to have read the data from the google fit cloud and display on their client app.
I tried to do the same but with no luck.

As i could not get any information on the derived type and datasourceIds, datastream name for Health Datatypes, i decided to write a sample app using googleplayservices api.

1. First of all, the "Scopes" class still has not been extended with Bp and Glucose. So, i used the original scope string to add the scope in GoogleApiClient.Builder as follows.

   .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.read")).

This showed an authorization message to the user to "accept" and authorize. So, this seems to work.

2. This code snippet doesn't result in any runtime error but it doesnt return any valid dataSet (so it always returns -1).
   PendingResult result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotalFromLocalDevice(mClient, HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE);
           DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
               DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
               long total = totalSet.isEmpty()
                       ? -1
                       : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(HealthFields.FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SYSTOLIC).asInt();
               Log.i(TAG,"total : "+ total);
           } else {
               // handle failure
               Log.i(TAG,"total : request failed");
           }
3. I used Nokia Health Mate android app and there is an option to manually enter Blood Pressure Data. Also, connected this app to write into "Google Fit". But im not able to read any values using my code snippet. Also, i could not find any documentation if the data stored by the Nokia HealthMate is open for others to read. I understand this is a restricted datatype (to write) but should be available for all to read.

Comment: I think there is an open [bug report](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/issues/22) regarding reading HealthDataTypes, try following that report to be updated. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MohananR thanks for the scope value. i was searching for it.

Comment: Hi Sarath, if you have been able to find a device or an app that writes "health data" into googlefit, and able to read the same from your app, please update me.

Comment: @MohananR As far as i know, i'm able get weight log from google fit and write it to it

Comment: Have you solved?